# Install system to Disk on Chip

Tags: system-installation, disk

I'm looking for an easy way to install linux on a PC104 (x86 no cmov) system with a Disk-on-Chip. It can be a very simple system (BusyBox, etc) or a distro the installs in under 512mb. I  just need to boot to a prompt. Does anyone know a simple path to get this done?